# How to get client IP address in Go/Revel

Tags: http, go, revel

Howto get the client's IP Address in Revel?

In Beego:

```
func (this *baseController) getClientIp() string {
    s := strings.Split(this.Ctx.Request.RemoteAddr, ":")
    return s[0]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Foreword:** I released this utility in my [`github.com/icza/gox`](https://github.com/icza/gox) library, see [`httpx.ClientIP()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/gox/netx/httpx#ClientIP).

---

It's very similar in Revel too. The [`Controller`](http://revel.github.io/docs/godoc/controller.html#Controller) is a `struct` which contains the [`http.Request`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request), so from there you have access to `Request.RemoteAddr`, the one used in the above Beego example:

```
// ctrl is a struct embedding a pointer of github.com/revel/revel.Controller
s := strings.Split(ctrl.Request.RemoteAddr, ":")
ip := s[0]
```

Or in one line:

```
ip := strings.Split(ctrl.Request.RemoteAddr, ":")[0]
```

**Note:** There is no standard form for the value of the `RemoteAddr`. It can be an IPv4 or an IPv6 address, it may or may not contain port, so the above algorithm (copied from the question) will not work in every case. The question was directed at how to obtain this `RemoteAddr` and not how to parse it particularly. To easily parse address strings, use [`net.SplitHostPort()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#SplitHostPort), like:

```
host, port, err := net.SplitHostPort(ctrl.Request.RemoteAddr)
```

**Note #2:** If the request gets forwarded and/or goes through proxy servers, the `RemoteAddr` field may not denote the original client that sent the request. Usually when a request is forwarded / goes through proxies, the original client is added in an HTTP header field called `X-Forwarded-For`, which you can get like

```
ip := c.Request.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For")
```

Comment: Request.RemoteAddr return 127.0.0.1

Comment: Return real IP   ip := c.Request.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For")

Comment: Add Utils GetIp https://github.com/zzdboy/GoCMS/blob/master/app/controllers/User/user.go#L205

Comment: The answer should be changed to what @NiltonOS responded, the above does not work.